To what extent are UK government finances known to the Opposition?
After taking office Rachel Reeves, the new Labour chancellor revealed that the UK's finances are in a worse than expected state, including a £22bn black hole, previous unknown to the Labour party and the country.
Jeremy Hunt, hits back saying this is not true.
It's not the first time changing party has met with disagreement about the state of public finances.
To what extent is the true financial state of  UK plc hidden from everyone outside the current government?

FWTW, the 'black hole' seems to be spending commitments with no allocated source of funding.

Did they state when this 22bn shortfall is relevant? It is very common for governments to use overly optimistic planning for the future. A 22bn shortfall for this years budget is major news. An expected shortfall of 22bn over the next years based on slightly adjusted predictions about future revenue and spending is just normal.

@quarague "It is very common for governments to use overly optimistic planning for the future." And before a new election governments are probably extremely optimistic as well as after an election the new government is much more realistic. Hence the 22bn difference.

And don't forget creative accounting. I recently read that part of German government efforts of decreasing next year's budget is assuming that a larger than previously thought part of funds will not be able to be effectively used. Only now this effect is already part of the calculation. It's not a cut but it's also a cut.

The opposition get no special access to government accounts, audits, etc.  They have the same sources of information that are publically accessible to the media, such as reports from the Office of Budgetary Responsibility.
Some possible exceptions to this may include private briefings between MPs, or leaks from the civil service.  But these are rare.
So all the "22 billion pound black hole" and "nonsense" is all political spin. It's clear that Labour won't implement everything in its manifesto, and they are going to "blame the Tories" for this.  The truth is probably somewhere in the middle, but (as Obi-Wan says) the truth may depend on your point of view.

If you look at the statement made by Hunt in the linked article, he says the hole is not as big because the 22bn contain 9.4bn to meet the public sector pay increases. So from his point of view there is a  shortfall of 13bn plus whatever the public sector pay increase will cost. He phrased it slightly differently but the Tories admit there is a double digit billion hole.

"The opposition get no special access to government accounts, audits, etc." - I don't think this is totally true in this case, the civil service had the green light to hold access talks with the opposition as early as January.

Not a downvote but the Civil Service do have substantial talks with the opposition parties during an election campaign  https://www.instituteforgovernment.org.uk/explainer/civil-service-prepares-general-election

The U.K. government is quite transparent about its existing finances. It isn't publicly published to any level of detail one might desire, which a member of the government can request, but it is out there and accurate, because U.K. civil servants are not very corrupt. More information is available in many instances upon request, if someone is smart enough to guess what to ask for.
The dispute referenced in the question isn't about that, however. It is about projected government deficits based upon projected revenues and projected expenses. More specifically, it is about "unfunded promises" of more spending than in the status quo (from the second link in the question), rather than inaccuracies that were primarily about funding existing programs.
Unlike existing finances, projecting future government finances involves myriad economic assumptions that are a constantly moving target. Predicting future tax revenues requires a fairly fine grained set of assumptions about future economic growth by each sector of the economy that drives a different mix of tax revenues. Predicting future expenses requires accurate actuarial predictions, some of which, like inflation and decisions about when to retire, can be thrown off rapidly. Econometric predictions are as much art as science.
One of the whole reasons that a parliament is necessary in the first place is that taxing and spending decisions need to be regularly tweaked to reflect differences between projected tax revenues and government spending, and actual tax revenues and government spending.
The information available to cabinet level official in the U.K. government and their senior budget advisors that are used to make these predictions are, particularly on the revenue side, at best, marginally better than the information available to the general public, and more often, marginally worse than the information being used by the top financial companies in the City of London.
Important sources of macroeconomic uncertainty including the rate at which economic realities return to normal following the massive disruptions of COVID-19 (which started in early 2020) and the Ukraine War (which started in early 2022 and dramatically impacted fossil fuel prices and prices for certain food stuffs in international markets). The economists also have to work out the ongoing impact of Brexit which is a major disruptor to economic models developed while the U.K. was part of the European Union. And, those are just the top line factors. There are probably at least a dozen more factors that are less dramatic, but still important enough to impact government budget forecasting and contribute materially to a £20-22 billion shortfall.
Some perspective is in order as well. "For the financial year 2023-24, total government spending is expected to be £1,189 billion." And, expected revenue in the U.K. was £1,058 billion. (Source).
The £20-22 billion shortfall is equivalent to overestimating revenue by a little less than 1% and underestimating spending by a little less than 1%. While it is true that £20-22 billion is not chump change, this is well within the range of normal inaccuracy in forecasting for government budgets.
Suppose that you are shopkeeper, who made £50,000 last year. Your sales are coming in at £500 less than you'd projected for the year, and your expenses are up £500 from what you'd projected for the year due to higher utility bills, food expenses, and the fact that you had to hire someone to replace some inventory destroyed when a new employee accidentally set the thermostat on the store refrigerator too high. As a result, the kids are going to get skimpier presents for Christmas and on their birthdays this year, and your going to have to vacation at less nice hotel than you'd planned. This is what the U.K.'s financial shortfall looks like translated to household scale.
The bottom line is that while the opposition does indeed have less access to government financial data than the cabinet does (although roughly the same information as is available to back benchers in the majority in parliament), the differences in access to information aren't the most material factor in a "surprise" increase in the projected budget deficit which is less than 2% of annual government spending. And, the impact as a percentage of annual revenues and expenses may be smaller than that, as it isn't entirely clear from the news report that the shortfall is for a single fiscal year.
